# Understanding leakCanary output

Tags: android, leakcanary

I'm having trouble understanding the LeakCanary output.
I know I'll have to post some code, but I need some guidance into where to start, since it's a whole lot of code.
The ouput looks something like:

```
* ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.this$0
|
| references
* ViewRootImpl.mOldFocusedView
|
| references
* ListView.mOnScrollListener
|
| references
* MyFragment.launcer
|
|
* leaks MyLauncher instance
```

`MyLauncher` is a class that extends `LinearLayout` and holds a strong reference to the fragment it launches. 
I put a reference watch on this launcher when it is being removed from the main layout.
It seems like I am leaking this launcher.
Where do I start?

Comment: If you are manually setting a scroll listener on a `ListView`, try unregistering that in `onDestroy()` of the activity. Otherwise, my guess is that this is an Android problem, not yours. There are a few leaks that show up in this area that are Android's problem, such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205171).